# The write operation doesn't update the characteristic value for iOS in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm creating a **BLE application** using xamarin forms. **Everything is working fine in Android** I'm able to read and write GATT characteristics. In iOS I'm able to read successfully but the **write operation doesn't update the characteristics value**. There is **no error in the write operation** as well it is executing but the characteristics value is not changing. I tried iOS native application called **light blue** there its working fine the characteristic value is updated I'm facing issue only in Xamarin forms app. This is my code

```
 private async Task<string> ProcessDeviceInformationService(IService deviceInfoService)
        {
            try
            {
               await adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device);
                var sb = new StringBuilder("Getting information from Device Information service: \n");
                 var characteristics =  deviceInfoService.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
                var characteristic = await deviceInfoService.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse("00002a2b-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                
                try
                {
                    
                    if (characteristic != null)
                    {
                        var sbnew = new StringBuilder("BLE Characteristics\n");
                        byte[] senddata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.IsNullOrEmpty(SendMessageLabel.Text) ? "12" : SendMessageLabel.Text);

 

                       
                    
                                                    
                                                 
                        
                        characteristic.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
                          {
                        
                         var bytes = characteristic.Value;
                                                 };
                                               await characteristic.WriteAsync(senddata);

 

                                                                                                     
                      

 

                        string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(senddata);

 

                  

 

                        sbnew.AppendLine($"Characteristics found on this device: {string.Join(", ", str.ToString())}");
                            CharactericsLabel.Text = sbnew.ToString();
                        

 


                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //return ex.Message;
                    DisplayAlert("Notice", ex.Message.ToString(), "OK");

 

                }
```

I tried delay and I also tried to get write without response from peripheral but it doesn't work. This is my peripheral code

```
 // Current Time characteristic
BluetoothGattCharacteristic currentTime = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(CURRENT_TIME,
        //Read-only characteristic, supports notifications
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE,
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE);
BluetoothGattDescriptor configDescriptor = new BluetoothGattDescriptor(CLIENT_CONFIG,
        //Read/write descriptor
        BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_WRITE);
currentTime.addDescriptor(configDescriptor);
// Local Time Information characteristic
BluetoothGattCharacteristic localTime = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(LOCAL_TIME_INFO,
        //Read-only characteristic
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ,
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);
BluetoothGattCharacteristic sampleText = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic sampleText = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(SAMPLE_TEXT,
        //Read-only characteristic
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY,
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);
```

I have no clue how to fix this any suggestions.I tried even Semaphore but it didn't help as you can see in my code

```
private static async Task<string> WriteAndWaitForResponseAsync(
    ICharacteristic characteristic,
    byte[] senddata)
        {
            var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
            string result = null;

            characteristic.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
            {
                var bytes = characteristic.Value;

                result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);  // Note I don't know if this is your intended behaviour with the values you get back, you can decide what to actually do with the response.
                                                          // Notify a value has been received.
                semaphore.Release();
            };

            await characteristic.WriteAsync(senddata,new CancellationToken(true)).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Wait until we receive a notification.
            await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // I strongly suggest you look in to CancellationTokens but I am not going in to that now.
           
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: You need to issue a read request after you write the data. Your code doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: @Paulw11 await characteristic.ReadAsync() does that right? Do you mean in peripheral side? I didn't try read from peripheral side because I'm able to get the updated characteristic value for Android using code  characteristic.ReadAsync()  but why it is not showing for iOS then?

Comment: I don't know xamarin forms but I do know that time delays are a code smell. Your code should not depend on timing. For example, you should issue the characteristic read in the `ValueUpdated` block.

Comment: @Paulw11 do you mean adding code characteristic.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
                        {
                            var bytes = await characteristic.ReadAsync();
                        };

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried that it is not working. Please have a look into my source code and the BLE advertiser. If I have to do any changes in peripheral please let me know.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you subscribe for the `ValueUpdated` event **before** calling `WriteAsync`. Then you should not need to rely on `Task.Delay` or having to call `Read`. Relying on timing behaviour like this means you can run the risk of missing the data entirely

Comment: @Bijington can u check if there is any issue in advertiser code. I'll check your suggestion as well by removing the task delay and calling value updated before the writeasync.

Comment: Also which characteristic are you expecting to update/write to? The line that calls `deviceInfoService.GetCharacteristicAsync(GattCharacteristicIdentifiers.DataExchange);` doesn't assign the result so won't be used

Comment: Actually I'm using  var characteristics = await deviceInfoService.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
                var characteristic = await deviceInfoService.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse("00002A39-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")); that code I'm not using recently I added that by mistake.

Comment: When you inspect the device in LightBlue does it tell you that the characteristic you wish to read from supports `Read` or `Notify` or both?

Comment: @Bijington yes it has read and notify feature also the write operation works in light blue app.

Comment: @Bijington I edited the code in my question as well as per your suggestion. I tried to call the value updated before write operation but it didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't even go inside to execute var bytes = characteristic.Value;

Comment: Ok then you may need to use something like a SemaphoreSlim to prevent you leaving that method before you have received the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that threading is part of the problem here and that you subscribe for the event, call `WriteAsync` but then you ultimately leave the method before the data/event has been received. I suggest you need to try blocking the method from leaving before you receive your data.

Try something like:

```
private static async Task<string> WriteAndWaitForResponseAsync(
    ICharacteristic characteristic,
    byte[] senddata)
{
    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    string result = null;

    characteristic.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
    {
        // Make sure you read from the new value in event not the existing characteristic.
        var bytes = args.Characteristic.Value;

        result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);  // Note I don't know if this is your intended behaviour with the values you get back, you can decide what to actually do with the response.
        // Notify a value has been received.
        semaphore.Release();
    };
    
    await characteristic.WriteAsync(senddata);

    // Wait until we receive a notification.
    await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // I strongly suggest you look in to CancellationTokens but I am not going in to that now.

    return result;
}
```

Then you can call this method from within your current one like:

```
string str = await WriteAndWaitForResponseAsync(characteristic, senddata);
```

Comment: I tried that but it gets locked in the semaphore.waitasync. Also  it doesn't go inside the characteristic valueupdated event or execute semaphore release or other code inside valueupdated  after write operation.

Comment: @JudsonAbraham that sounds like you are not actually getting a response back from the other device then. Can you try checking whether `await characteristic.WriteAsync(senddata);` succeeds?

Comment: @beijington the await characteristic.WriteAsync(senddata); executes and there is no error in device log as well. But the characteristristic value still remains the same it doesn't change. How can I check if the write operation succeeded other than checking the characteristic value.

Comment: Do I have to do something in advertiser for that?

Comment: @JudsonAbraham `await characteristic.WriteAsync(senddata);` should return a boolean result as to whether it succeeded or not. Sorry I have realised there is a flaw in my answer. It should be reading `characteristic.Value` in the event handler but `args.Characteristic.Value`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @beijington I get value false for newbytes for  code var newbytes = await characteristic.WriteAsync(senddata); It is false for both Android and iOS. But in Android it changes the characteristic value but for iOS it doesn't change value.

Comment: Sorry I’m not sure I know enough about the lower levels of the plug-in you are using. If you are getting ‘false’ returned for both platforms then it sounds like you are lucky that Android is working rather than it working properly. It might be worth checking the code on GitHub to see what it is actually doing

Comment: I'm using the Github plugin https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le but there I think there is not such issues.